# How do I create a custom connect stripe account and pass account id to payment intent method using firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, react-native, axios, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to collect and transfer payments using firebase cloud functions in my react native app. I'm using the stripe.accounts.create and stripe.paymentIntents.create functions as well as library axios. I'm really not too sure how to create the connect account and pass the account id created into the payment intent method. I get the following error in the firebase logs 'code: 'StripeInvalidRequestError: Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`)'
when trying to run my code below. Can someone please assist? I don't think the connectAcc.id is null since I can see it in my stripe dashboard logs in the response body where the account is created:

**Response body**
{
"id": "acct_**********U5",
"object": "account",
"business_profile": {
"mcc": "5734",
"name": null,
"product_description": null,
"support_address": null,
"support_email": null,
"support_phone": null,
"support_url": null,

**index.js file**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('**SK_LIVE**');

exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

const connectAcc = stripe.accounts.create({
type: 'custom',
email: 'name@gmail.com',
country: 'GB',
business_type: 'individual',
business_profile: {
   mcc: '5734',
   url: 'site.com',
},
individual: {
   first_name: 'First',
   last_name: 'Last',
   dob : {
     day: 1,
     month: 10,
     year: 1990
       },
   email: 'name@gmail.com',
   phone: '+44xxxxxxx',
   address: {
      city: 'city',
      country: 'GB',
      line1: '1',
      line2: 'Street Rd',
      postal_code: 'XXX XXX'
   }       
},
tos_acceptance: {
       date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
       ip: request.connection.remoteAddress,
    },
capabilities: {
   card_payments: {requested: true},
   transfers: {requested: true},
},
external_account: {
   object: 'bank_account',
       country: 'GB',
   currency: 'gbp',
   account_number: 'xxxxx',
   routing_number: 'xxxxx',
   accounter_holder_name: 'First Last',
   account_holder_type: 'individual',
  }
 })



 stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: request.body.amount,
    currency: request.body.currency,
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    payment_method: request.body.payment_method.id,
    application_fee_amount: 20,
    on_behalf_of: connectAcc.id,
    transfer_data: {
    destination: connectAcc.id,
    },
    confirm: true,
    description: 'UniHome'
    }

   ).then((charge) => {
        response.send(charge);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
    })

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of debugging have you done? Have you confirmed that either of those API requests are made by looking at the [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs) on your Stripe account and they don't error? Have you checked logs in Firebase or added console.logs to your own code? "could not handle the request" is a generic error, there must be logs that help you understand exactly how the request gets processed and which part might not be working.

Comment: thanks. It mentions that transfers needs to enabled 'invalid_request_error
Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments. There are a few fields that need to be filled when creating an account such business type, industry, website etc. Thanks

Comment: Yes, part of creating the account and sending money to it is first onboarding it and collecting identity verification from the user, for legal requirements. It's not as simple as just collecting a bank account number and sending money to it! I'd suggest reading Stripe's documentation on all this.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding // https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api // https://support.stripe.com/questions/know-your-customer-obligations

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to provide the requirements in order to setup a connected account and it appears in my stripe dashboard when running but the funds are not being transferred. The logs from my firebase functions shows : StripeInvalidRequestError: Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment...

Comment: Then you're not making a destination charge. Almost certainly your `account.id` variable in that code above is null, so `transfer_data` is not being sent, you should be able to compare what you see in the logs to that code to debug if the log doesn't match what you think the code is doing.

Comment: I updated my function as above where I created a const variable for account and tried to call the connectAcc.id. I don't think this is null as I can see the id in the dashboard but then again I cannot confirm this as I'm not too sure how to check this in the firebase logs. Using console.log(connectAcc.id) doesn't seem to show anything in the firebase logs

Comment: Still getting this error: StripeInvalidRequestError: Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`)

Comment: Can anyone help please? connectAcc.id appears to be null. How do I get the id from the stripe account I create? Am I not creating the account correctly here?

Comment: `connectAcc` is not an account object — it's a Promise, right? That's what Stripe's SDK returns. You'd have to resolve the Promise first, like `let connectAcc = await stripe.accounts.create(...); let id = connectAcc.id` or `stripe.accounts.create(...).then(function(acct){let id = acct.id;} )`

Comment: @karllekko Would you kindly post this solution as an answer for future readers?

Answer (score 1):

`connectAcc` is not an account object — it's a Promise. That's what Stripe's SDK returns.

You'd have to resolve the Promise first, like:

`let connectAcc = await stripe.accounts.create(...); let id = connectAcc.id or stripe.accounts.create(...).then(function(acct){let id = acct.id;} )`